# How to break an iteration on file lines in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, iteration, stdin, break

I have a reading thread in my application that listens on `stdin`. It blocks until some input is available. When some arrive, it accepts the lines, checks if they are valid commands and put them in a queue.

```
def ReadCommands( queue ):
    for cmd in stdin:
        if cmd=="":
            break
        # Check if cmd is valid and add to queue

queue = Queue()
thread = Thread( target=ReadCommands, args=( queue, ) )
thread.start()
```

Now when the main program wants to exit, it first has to join on this reading thread. The problem is that the thread is in a loop I have no control over. Even `stdin.close()` does not work.

How can I break the for loop in the reading thread from the main?

Alternatively, how can I write the for loop (with a while?) to be able to add my own boolean variable that would break the loop? Beware that I don't want an active waiting loop!

Comment: threading.event may help you. You can check exit condition by is_set().

Comment: This is the link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects

Comment: I don't think this is related to your problem, but isn't `args` supposed to be a tuple? In which case you should do `args=(queue,)`

Comment: @Kevin Yes. Thanks. (I have two arguments in my actual code ...)

Comment: @AnakinTung My problem is not to communicate to the reading thread that I want to stop. My problem is within the reading thread, how to add such a condition in the `for cmd in stdin` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have threads that you just want to shut down on exiting your program, starting them in [daemon mode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) is often the best way to go. If all non-daemon threads exit, your application will end, taking all daemon threads with it.

Note that you should only do this for threads that do not have to perform cleanup; your example seems to be fine for this.
Also, if you are performing a blocking C-level operation, a daemon thread may still block until it returns to the actual python scope. In that case, there is no python level option to break the block to begin with. Reading from broken sockets can be such an issue, for example.

---

If you need to explicitly kill a blocking thread before stopping your program, you will probably have to use the [python's C-API](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496960-thread2-killable-threads/). This can be implemented more cleanly but works in principle.